# Stateful implementation of yaml.v2 Unmarshaller interface?

Tags: go

This could either be a file path question, or a question on how to best implement an interface.

Given the following very simple yaml:

```
name: MyYamlName
data: some/relative/path.txt
```

I would like to unmarshal it to the following struct:

```
type VerySimple struct {
    name string
    data io.Reader
}
```

I'm already using the [yaml.v2 library](http://gopkg.in/yaml.v2), and know that for simple types, I can implement the [Unmarshaller](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshaler) interface. However, in my program, I can't assume an absolute root from which to base the relative path in the `data` field.

Is there a way to implement the `Unmarshaller` interface to pass a working directory, or maybe a different way to handle relative paths in Go?

Comment: If feels that in this case a post processing is perhaps simpler, especially if your yaml is small and simple. Meaning let lib to it's work and then simply modify your `VerySimple.data` to fit your actual path.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear from the [API documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2) that this isn't supported. The natural way to support it, IMO, would be with a Decoder type, analogous to the [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) type. It could be initialized with a root include path, or a list of include paths to search.

There is [already a request](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/issues/4) for such a feature. It does mention working with multiple documents, which probably implies including an include path, although that specific feature has not yet been explicitly mentioned. I suggest offering your ideas in that thread.